# Serializable on ArrayList losing some data

Tags: java, serializable

I have an ArrayList of Employee objects where Employee class implements Serializable. I am using this code to write lists to a file:

```
ArrayList<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("EmpObject.ser");
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  // write object to file
  empList .add(emp1);
  empList .add(emp2);
  oos.writeObject(empList);

  empList .add(emp3);

  oos.writeObject(empList);
}
```

If I try to de-serialize it I am just getting first two objects not the 3rd one. Can anyone please try why is it?

edit1: If I add all elements at once everything is fine but not the way I did first. What is the difference?

```
ArrayList<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("EmpObject.ser");
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  // write object to file
  empList .add(emp1);
  empList .add(emp2);
  empList .add(emp3);
  oos.writeObject(empList);
}
```

After this I have 3 elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As GhostCat and uaraven already mentioned reset does not what you are expecting it to do and you should have a look at a tutorial on serialization and maybe consider using sth. else if this isn't fitting your use case.

Your code could look as follows if creating a new FileOutputStream:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SerializationTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String path = "EmpObject.ser";

        ArrayList<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));

        empList.add(emp1);
        empList.add(emp2);
        oos.writeObject(empList);

        empList.add(emp3);
        // Create a new FileOutputStream to override the files content instead of appending the new employee list
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(path));
        oos.writeObject(empList);

        ObjectInputStream objectinputstream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        List<Employee> readCase = (List<Employee>) objectinputstream.readObject();

        System.out.println(readCase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much everyone. Went through the tutorial. Got it now. Just needed to create a new output stream like mentioned by @FlorianDe. Thank u so much for the help

Answer (score 3):

What happens with your code:

- you write the list into the file, with **two** entries
- you reset the stream
- you write the list again, with **three** entries

Thus your file contains **two** values, yes. Two lists, one with 2, one with 3 entries.

In other words: `reset()` doesn't **reset** what has been written to the file! You wrote **one** list with two entries. You are only **resetting** the information about stored objects, so that emp1 and emp2 get **serialized** completely again. Without the call to reset, the JVM would understand that it doesn't need to fully serialize emp1 and emp2 again.

Meaning: by default the JVM **compresses** the amount of data to transmit. It remembers which objects where already written, and instead of writing them repeatedly, it only writes something like "object X that was serialized earlier on comes again" into the stream.

So: I think you  simply do **not** understand the point of the `reset()` method. Solution: read a small tutorial, like the one from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/objectoutputstream_reset.htm).

Edit given the latest comment by the OP:

What you ask for isn't possible in this way. You are writing **list** objects. That means that all entries of that list at that point get written to the file. The JVM remembers "that list has been written already", so it will **not** write it again, even when its internal state changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `ObjectOutputStream` remembers objects that are written to it. If the same object (by reference) is written again, it is not serialized, but rather a reference to previous serialized data is written to stream. `reset()` method cleans up internal data structures of `ObjectOutputStream` and allows you to write the same object again. `reset()` does not discard data already written to the stream.

If you try to deserialize your stream into two ArrayLists, you'll get one with two elements and one with three elements.

If you remove call to `reset()` method, then you will get two array lists with two elements (one actually serialized, and another as a reference to the previous serialized instance)

Comment: The OP calls reset in his first example, and he says it still doesn't work?

Comment: Actually I dont want to reset() . I just want one ArrayList with 3 elements, BUT I DONT want to add all the elements in the list at once. First 2 elements and then one more.

Comment: If you want to write ArrayList once, then write it once. You cannot write Array list with two elements to a file and then expect to read three elements from it. 
You can create a new FileOutputStream and overwrite the data already written to it, but you cannot append new data to the same stream and expect that previously written data somehow disappears.

Comment: oh so it is not possible to do this way then What is the best way to write and then deserialize it

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand what I was trying to do was not possible. Thanks